# How to sort using statement of C# code in vim?

Tags: c#, vim, stylecop

Recently I edit C# code in vim. And the build system has StyleCop enabled so that all **using** statement should be in alphabetical order.

So, I tried to select below lines of code in visual mode, then type ":sort".

```
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security;
using System.ServiceModel;
```

The result is:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security;
using System.ServiceModel;
```

It doesn't pass StyleCop checking because "System.Security" is not ahead of "System.Security.Permissions". The ASCII value of ";" is larger than ASCII value of ".".

The preferred result is:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.ServiceModel;
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:h :sort` is your friend:

```
:[range]sort r /[^;]*/
```

If along the way you wish to remove duplicates, add the **u**niq flag:

```
:[range]sort ur /[^;]*/
```

(This won't do any good if you have different comments after the ';' though)

Comment: Thanks. To make it better, we can remove duplicate using statements with:

:[range]sort ur /[^;]*/

Answer (score 1):

```
:1,4s/;$//
:sort
:1,4s/$/;/
```

(where 1,4 are lines with using statements)

Comment: This is a solution, even though it takes a lot of typing:)

Comment: Try this one (select your using statements and press F5):

:map <F5> :s/;/ /g<cr>gv:sort<cr>gv:s/ /;/g<cr>

Answer (score 0):

Not using CodeRush or ReSharper is stealing from your employer

`<ducks for downvotes>`

(Yes, I know that requires VS (and AFAIK VS10 has this OOTB))

Comment: @Konamiman: No, but if I for some reason felt I had to use vim, I'd shell out to VS to get either of them

Comment: There are a lot of microsoftees work with VIM rather than VS like me:)

Comment: @Morgan: I know - only yanking chains. (Although I find it very hard to imagine myself in a parallel universe, coding away in a language that grabs its ankles for you to use a refactoring tool and then wilfully ignoring it.)  Yes I understand that VS can hardly be described as a scriptable editor. Maybe reading Clean Code, APPP, Refactoring and using xunit.net and CR have just warped my worldview too much :P

Answer (score 0):

On my linux box with a local other than C (tested fr_FR, fr_FR.UTF-8, en_US, en_GB), the sort command sorts as you expect. You could very well pipe to the sort command :

```
:1,4!sort
```

If you are on windows, I suppose you can install unix tools (like SFU) that could do the job since vim's sort command doesn't seem to handle locale.